# Website messes up on larger screens and shows scrollbar on smaller ones

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website, I tried everything and still haven't found a solution.

I want to make my website look almost identical in all computer screen sizes.
When I test it on larger screens, a gap appears betweeen the footer and the rest of the page contents.
When I test it on smaller screens, it shows fine but you have to scroll vertically and horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Royal Scottish Country Dance Society</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/general.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    src: url('../Fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf'); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold';
    src: url('Fonts/MyriadPro-Bold.otf');   
}
p {font-size:65%; text-align:left; padding-right:18%;}

h2 {
    font-size:98%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 class="alignleft"> RSCDS <span style="font-size:30%">Royal Scottish Country Dance Society</span></h1>
    <h1 class="alignright"> Call us on <span>07459107891</span><br/>
      for any further details </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="vmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html"><span class="current">Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="confweek.html">Conference<br>
        Weeekend</a></li>
      <li><a href="danceprog.html">Dance<br>
        Program</a></li>
      <li><a href="teachers.html">Teachers</a></li>
      <li><a href="travel.html">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="stay.html">Where to Stay</a></li>
      <li><a href="join.html">Join Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="vmenu2"></div>
  <img id="pattern2" src="Patterns/im4.jpg"/> <img id="pattern" src="Patterns/Pattern_1.jpg"/>
    <div id="pagewrap">
      <h2>Welcome to the royal scottish country<br>
        dance society</h2>
      <p> The youth groups of the RSCDS run a weekend conference every year. The event runs from Friday evening to Sunday lunchtime, and is a mixture of Scottish country dance and other classes for all levels of dancers from beginners to advanced along with meetings, evening dances and other social events. Young dancers in each area take it in turns to host the event and it is anticipated that the event will be held in Glasgow in 2015. Join us for a totally unique dance experience. With three days of performances, classes, advice and fun, RSCDS is your chance to design your perfect day of dance. <br>
        <br>
        There's plenty to choose from no matter your ability level. </p>
      <h2>WHOEVER YOU ARE, WHEREVER YOU ARE <br/> FROM, COME DANCE WITH US!</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    min-height: 9.5%;
    background: #4F4F50;
    position: relative;
}
div#footer {
    margin: 0;
    background: #4F4F50;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 5.5%;
}
div#pagewrap {
    padding: 1.77% 20% 0% 15.5%;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro Regular";
    width: 27%;
}
div#vmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2% 1% 0% 0%;
    background: #09051A;
    width: 12%;
    height: 672px;
    float: left;
}
div#vmenu2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #09051A;
    width: 12%;
    height: 672px;
    float: right;
}
div#vmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
div#vmenu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
div#vmenu ul a:link {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6% 8% 5% 0%;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
div#vmenu ul a:visited {
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    color: #ffffff;
}
div#vmenu ul li a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-size: medium;
    color: #289280;
}
img#pattern {
    width: 31%;
    padding: 3% 5.5% 3.5% 2%;
    float: right;
}
img#pattern2 {
    height: 668px;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 6.7%;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 668px;
}
h1 span {
    font-size: 180%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 110%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro Bold";
}
h3 {font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold';
}
p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #289280;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    min-width: 1440px;
    position: relative;
}
.alignleft {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 400%;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold';
    padding: 0.7% 0% 0% 1.3%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
.alignright {
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold';
    padding: 1.2% 0% 1.3% 82.5%;
    position: absolute;
}
.current {
    color: #289280;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Media Queries in CSS3 take this idea and extend it. Rather than looking for a type of device they look at the capability of the device, and you can use them to check for all kinds of things. For example:

1.width and height (of the browser window)
 2.device width and height
 3.orientation – for example is a phone in landscape or portrait mode?
 4.resolution

for example:

1) mobile screen

2) tablet screen

3) Desktop screen

4) Ipad screen

Comment: Also I want to mention one important thing that is you can not render your website same as desktop on perticular device/screen. you need to make your website responsive.